# How to Open a PDF File in .NET MAUI Android and iOS

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios

I want to open PDF files which in `/Resources/Raw` folder in my .NET MAUI project. Firstly I tried to use Syncfusion extension but it didn't worked for me. Then I used `WebView Grid.Row` which works very well in Windows. I added the code and screenshot while running in Windows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit" //I added this one and added WebView Grid.Row
         x:Class="borkatalogYeni.PdfViewer"
         Title="PdfViewer">

<Grid>
    <WebView Grid.Row="1"
             HorizontalOptions="Fill"
             VerticalOptions="Fill"
             Source="Reference.pdf"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: The Program running in Windows]

But the problem that when I start the project in virtual Android device it's not responding, there's only a white page. It gives same reaction to real device too. Before that, I added `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. I added the screenshot for "the white page"

[image: The White Page that I got while running project in Android]

For iOS, I couldn't tried yet because I don't have any Mac or iOS.

I can't find any solutions for Android and iOS platforms. Is there any solutions that I can handle this without using any paid extensions? Kind regards.